# How can I get a div to extend to the full height of its parent div of variable height?

Tags: css, height

I have a container div, in it I have a left div and a main div. The left div needs to be the same height as the main div, even when the main div is much taller than the left div's content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern (IE8+) browsers support `display:table` so you might want to use this solution:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TPBSW/1)**

```
.div1 {
  /* ... */
  display:table;        /* display table on parent*/
}
.div2, {
    /* ... */
    width:50%; 
    display:table-cell; /* display table-cell on children*/
}
.div3 {
    /* ... */
    width:50%; 
    display:table-cell;
 }
```